# Send Javascript UTC from client to Classic ASP application with Query String

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, utc

I'm trying to convert a local time event - 8AM - stored on db - to the client's local time in another country.

- Event in Mexico City 8AM to Paris, for example.

I don't know JS but I can identify the local time in the client machine with this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
}
</script>
```

Now I trying to send this value to CLASSIC ASP - back to server.

To do this I trying to create a link to send the information in a query string.

```
www.domain.com/login.asp?utc=XXXX
```

THen I can get the UTC time from client and convert with Classic ASP (I have better knowledge of Classic ASP)

Another easy way is to create a SESSION in JS - but I don't know how and I it's works with CLassic ASP sessions too.

Any idea?
tks!

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using browser cookies and Classic ASP's [Response.Cookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524757(v=vs.90).aspx) collection to do this.  The Javascript to do this is pretty simple:

```
// get the current date from the user's local machine
var now = new Date();

/*
The getTimezoneOffset() function returns the timezone offset in minutes.

If you want to convert dates from UTC to the user's local time
based on the timezone the user has set on their machine you need to 
multiple the result by -1.

This method does have the caveat that it assumes the user has set
their local machine's timezone information correctly.
*/
var offset = -now.getTimezoneOffset();

// write a cookie to the user's browser with the offset
document.cookie = "offset_to_utc="+offset
```

You could check to see if the cookie already exists rather than checking the user's timezone each time; however, if the user changes their timezone information during the same session, the change would not be reflected.

On the next page load and any page loads in the same browser session, you can retrieve the cookie you just set on the server side using Response.Cookies:

```
Dim OffsetToUTC
OffsetToUTC = Response.Cookies("offset_to_utc").Value
'Since cookies can be modified by users, it is a good idea to check the type
'of the data retrieved and convert it to an integer only if it is numeric.
If IsNumeric(OffsetToUTC) Then
   OffsetToUTC = CInt(OffsetToUTC)
Else
   OffsetToUTC = 0
End If
```

To convert a date in the database stored in UTC to the user's local time would look something like this:

```
Dim DBDate
DBDate = '<Replace with your code to get the date from the database>'
Response.Write(DateAdd("n", OffsetToUTC, DBDate))
```

Comment: hi @ThatGuyInIT - First of all, tks for your time and help! sorry for the delay - I'm trying to put your idea in work - and test - and its finally ok! tks a lot!!!! :D